# Uploading a file to testcontainer FTP server fails with Connection refused after being connected

Tags: java, ftp, ftp-client, testcontainers, apache-commons-net

I'm working with [FTPClient](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) against an FTP server using `Testcontainers`.

A reproducible code sample is here:

```
import org.apache.commons.net.PrintCommandListener;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPReply;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer;
import org.testcontainers.images.builder.ImageFromDockerfile;
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Testcontainers;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

@Testcontainers
class FtpUtilsTest {

    private static final int PORT = 21;
    private static final String USER = "user";
    private static final String PASSWORD = "password";
    private static final int FTP_TIMEOUT_IN_MILLISECONDS = 1000 * 60;

    private static final GenericContainer ftp = new GenericContainer(
        new ImageFromDockerfile()
            .withDockerfileFromBuilder(builder ->
                builder
                    .from("delfer/alpine-ftp-server:latest")
                    .build()
            )
    )
        .withExposedPorts(PORT)
        .withEnv("USERS", USER + "|" + PASSWORD);


    @BeforeAll
    public static void staticSetup() throws IOException {
        ftp.start();
    }

    @AfterAll
    static void afterAll() {
        ftp.stop();
    }

    @Test
    void test() throws IOException {
        FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
        ftpClient.setDataTimeout(FTP_TIMEOUT_IN_MILLISECONDS);
        ftpClient.setConnectTimeout(FTP_TIMEOUT_IN_MILLISECONDS);
        ftpClient.setDefaultTimeout(FTP_TIMEOUT_IN_MILLISECONDS);

        // Log
        ftpClient.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out), true));

        // Connect
        try {
            ftpClient.connect("localhost", ftp.getMappedPort(PORT));
            ftpClient.setSoTimeout(FTP_TIMEOUT_IN_MILLISECONDS);

            int reply = ftpClient.getReplyCode();
            if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
                ftpClient.disconnect();
                throw new AssertionError();
            }

            // Login
            boolean loginSuccess = ftpClient.login(USER, PASSWORD);
            if (!loginSuccess) {
                throw new AssertionError();
            }

            ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }

        String remoteFile = "fileonftp";
        try (InputStream targetStream = new ByteArrayInputStream("Hello FTP".getBytes())) {
            assertThat(ftpClient.isConnected()).isTrue();
            ftpClient.storeFile(remoteFile, targetStream);
        }
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
220 Welcome Alpine ftp server https://hub.docker.com/r/delfer/alpine-ftp-server/
USER *******
331 Please specify the password.
PASS *******
230 Login successful.
TYPE I
200 Switching to Binary mode.
PASV
227 Entering Passive Mode (172,17,0,3,82,15).
[Replacing PASV mode reply address 172.17.0.3 with 127.0.0.1]
```

then fails with:

```
Connection refused (Connection refused)
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    ...
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._openDataConnection_(FTPClient.java:866)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._storeFile(FTPClient.java:1053)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.storeFile(FTPClient.java:3816)
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.storeFile(FTPClient.java:3846)
```

What I don't understand is that it fails after successfully connecting and logging in, and returning `true` for `isConnected`.

---

Turns out that when removing the `ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();` it works, but I need it to work with the passive mode.

I guess the failure is related when switching to a different port for the passive call.

but when trying to add the ports to the `withExposedPorts` the container fails to start with:

```
Caused by: org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Timed out waiting for container port to open (localhost ports: [55600, 55601, 55602, 55603, 55604, 55605, 55606, 55607, 55608, 55609, 55598, 55599] should be listening)
```

---

Running against a docker (`docker run -d -p 21:21 -p 21000-21010:21000-21010 -e USERS="user|password" delfer/alpine-ftp-server`) works.

Local docker versions:

- Docker version 20.10.11, build dea9396
- Docker Desktop 4.3.1

Testcontainers - appears to behave the same both on 1.16.2 and 1.15.3

Link to testcontainers [discussion](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/discussions/4787)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you already figured out in the comments, the tricky part about FTP passive mode is that the server uses another port (not 21) for communication.
In the docker image you're using, it's a port from the `21000-21010` range by default. So you need to publish (expose) these additional container ports. In `docker run` command you used `-p 21000-21010:21000-21010` for that.

However, Testcontainers library is designed to publish to random host ports to avoid the problem, when a desired fixed port (or a range of ports) is already occupied on the host side.
In case of FTP passive mode random ports on the host side cause problems, because afaik you can't instruct the ftp client to override the port, which FTP server returned for the passive mode. You'd need something like `ftpClient.connect("localhost", ftp.getMappedPort(PORT));` but for passive mode ports as well.

Therefore the only solution I see here is to use a [FixedHostPortContainer](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/testcontainers/containers/FixedHostPortGenericContainer.java). Even though it's marked as deprecated and not recommended to use because of the mentioned issues with occupied ports, I think this is a valid use case for it here. `FixedHostPortGenericContainer` allows to publish fixed ports on the host side. Something like:

```java
    private static final int PASSIVE_MODE_PORT = 21000;
    ...
    private static final FixedHostPortGenericContainer ftp = new FixedHostPortGenericContainer<>(
            "delfer/alpine-ftp-server:latest")
            .withFixedExposedPort(PASSIVE_MODE_PORT, PASSIVE_MODE_PORT)
            .withExposedPorts(PORT)
            .withEnv("USERS", USER + "|" + PASSWORD)
            .withEnv("MIN_PORT", String.valueOf(PASSIVE_MODE_PORT))
            .withEnv("MAX_PORT", String.valueOf(PASSIVE_MODE_PORT));
```

Keep in mind that this solution relies on the assumption that `21000` port is always free. If you're going to run this in the environment where it's not guaranteed, then you need to tweak it to find a free host port first. Like:

```java
    private static FixedHostPortGenericContainer ftp = new FixedHostPortGenericContainer<>(
            "delfer/alpine-ftp-server:latest")
            .withExposedPorts(PORT)
            .withEnv("USERS", USER + "|" + PASSWORD);

    @BeforeAll
    public static void staticSetup() throws Exception {
        Integer freePort = 0;
        try (ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(0)) {
            freePort = socket.getLocalPort();
        }
        ftp = (FixedHostPortGenericContainer)ftp.withFixedExposedPort(freePort, freePort)
                .withEnv("MIN_PORT", String.valueOf(freePort))
                .withEnv("MAX_PORT", String.valueOf(freePort));

        ftp.start();
    }
```

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer! I'll try it out later today.

Comment: You might be able to override `FTPClient._parsePassiveModeReply` to apply `getMappedPort` to the passive mode port number.

Comment: The solution almost worked for me, I needed to expose additional ports in order to have it working (Kotlin version): `var container: FixedHostPortGenericContainer<*> = FixedHostPortGenericContainer<Nothing>("delfer/alpine-ftp-server:latest")
  .withExposedPorts(21)
 container.withEnv("USERS", "user|password123!")
 container.withFixedExposedPort(21, 21)
 container.withFixedExposedPort(21000, 21000)
 container.withEnv("MIN_PORT", "21000")
 container.withEnv("MAX_PORT", "21000")`

Answer (score 0):

An answer similar to the accepted one but without using deprecated functionalities.
Note that we still have to use the fixed port 21000.

```
public static class FTPContainer extends GenericContainer<FTPContainer>
{
   private static FTPContainer container;

   private FTPContainer()
   {
     super(DockerImageName.parse("delfer/alpine-ftp-server:latest"));
   }

   @SuppressWarnings("resource")
   public static FTPContainer getInstance()
   {
      if (container == null)
      {
         container = new FTPContainer().withEnv("USERS", "test|test|/home/").withExposedPorts(21)
              .withCreateContainerCmdModifier(e -> e.getHostConfig()
                    .withPortBindings(new PortBinding(Ports.Binding.bindPort(21000), new ExposedPort(21000))))
              .withEnv("MIN_PORT", "21000").withEnv("MAX_PORT", "21000");
      }
      return container;
   }

   @Override
   public void start()
   {
      super.start();
   }

   @Override
   public void stop()
   {
      // Handled when JVM stops
   }
}
```

And then you can use your FTP server instance like

```
FTPContainer FTP = FTPContainer.getInstance();
FTP.start();
```

Comment: this did not run , container fails with org.testcontainers.shaded.org.awaitility.core.ConditionTimeoutException: Lambda expression in org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer: expected the predicate to return <true> but it returned <false> for input of <InspectContainerResponse(args=[--, /bin/start_vsftpd.sh], config=ContainerConfig(attachStderr=false, attachStdin=false, attachStdout=false, cmd=null, domainName=, entrypoint=[/sbin/tini, --, /bin/start_vsftpd.sh], env=[MIN_PORT=21000, MAX_PORT=21000, USERS=free|free, PATH=

Answer (score 0):

I tried to put all peaces together.

```
class FtpContainer(private val params: CreationParams) :
    FixedHostPortGenericContainer<FtpContainer>("delfer/alpine-ftp-server:${params.version}") {

    override fun start() {
        val freePort = ServerSocket(0).use { socket -> socket.localPort }
        withFixedExposedPort(freePort, freePort)
            .withEnv("MIN_PORT", freePort.toString())
            .withEnv("MAX_PORT", freePort.toString())
            .withExposedPorts(21)
            .withEnv("USERS", "${params.user}|${params.password}")
        super.start()
    }

    fun getUrl(): String {
        return containerIpAddress
    }

    fun getFtpPort(): Int {
        return getMappedPort(21)
    }
}
```