# TestContainers FTP test fails

Tags: spring-boot, ftp, testcontainers

I have a simple test

```
   @TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
    class PurchaseFZ223FtpServiceTest {
    
        private static final int PORT = 21;
        private static final String USER = "";
        private static final String PASSWORD = "";
        private static final int PASSIVE_MODE_PORT =21000;
    
        @Container
          FixedHostPortGenericContainer<?> ftp = new FixedHostPortGenericContainer<>(
                "delfer/alpine-ftp-server:latest")
                .withFixedExposedPort(PASSIVE_MODE_PORT, PASSIVE_MODE_PORT)
                .withExposedPorts(PORT)
                .withEnv("USERS", USER + "|" + PASSWORD)
                .withEnv("MIN_PORT", String.valueOf(PASSIVE_MODE_PORT))
                .withEnv("MAX_PORT", String.valueOf(PASSIVE_MODE_PORT));
    
        private final FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
    
        @BeforeAll
        void init() throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException, IOException {
            ftp.start();
            client.connect("localhost", ftp.getMappedPort(PORT));
//some test logic
```

and everything works good when i start test on local pc,
and when i tried to build this with gitlab it start test and it always fails on client.connect("localhost", ftp.getMappedPort(PORT));

with exception: connection refused

do someone know what i missed or what is going wrong

ps. i checked for ftp is created and is running - and yes its running and its created, also i checked for ftp.getMappetPort(Port) and it will return something like this 53123

do not understand what do i miss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `FixedHostPortGenericContainer`, which is deprecated and which does not work in all environments. Especially CIs can be a problem, since the port might already be in use. Furthermore, on your CI, the container might not be reachable on `localhost`, which you use as a hardcoded value in `client.connect()`.

Also, when you use `FixedHostPortGenericContainer`, you should not use `getMappedPort()`, but can use the hardcoded port directly.

In order to make your configuration more robust, change to using `GenericContainer` together with `withExposedPort()`, `getHost()` (it might be the container is not reachable on `localhost`) and `getMappedPort()`.

Comment: the reason to use FixedHostPortGenericContainer is that we use passive ftp mode- and only way to test it - use FixedHostPortGenericContainer

Comment: read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70274689/uploading-a-file-to-testcontainer-ftp-server-fails-with-connection-refused-after

Comment: finally i connected to ftp by pass host and port to client that i got from server.getHost and server.getFirstMappedPort

Comment: But there is one more problem i cant store file client.storeFile("regions.txt",
                new ByteArrayInputStream("tverskaya_obl".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))));